# Save files from iOS share extension for use by host app

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, ios-sharesheet

I'm working on an app extension which I would like to allow users to share various files with the host app.

Example: Pick photo, choose share via app, photo is saved to shared folder & then available when user next opens host app.

I have the host app ready to read from the shared folder and the extension set up with just images for now, but the bit I'm stuck at is to retrieve the file data (blob or path I'm not sure?) and then write it to the shared folder.

Here is the relevant section from the extension:

```
 override func didSelectPost() {
    let content = extensionContext!.inputItems[0] as NSExtensionItem
    for attachment in content.attachments as [NSItemProvider] {

        // Image attachment
        if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String) {
            // save this to file in shared folder for host app to retrieve...
        }

    }

    self.extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems([], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

I've looked at many other questions but can't seem to find anything that fits my use case.

Answer (score 0):

*As I understand the question I just try to answer your question :*

> Please check the Plist file as below image :

[image]

If it's not same as i suggest then do it ...

and i hope,have you added the "**App Groups**" from select Project->**capabilities**...

---

> If above mention plist not working then go through the SUBQUERY as
>   following :

```
<key>NSExtenstionActivationRule</key>
<string>SUBQUERY (
            extensionItems,
            $extensionItem,
            SUBQUERY (
            $extensionItem.attachments,
            $attachment,

            (
            ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.png"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpeg"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpeg-2000"
            )
            ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
            ).@count == 1
</string>
```

> If then also not working then go through the

[App Extension by developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html)

I think, It'll Helps...

Comment: Thanks. I did have that part sorted out already, it was the code for saving to the group shared folder that I was having trouble with, though I've since gone back and re-implemented a different method with Obj C.